# Newbie issue is causing my code not to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm dealing with this piece of code and I'm going crazy since I can not find where my error is:

```
$.post($form.attr('action'), $form.serialize(), function (result) {
    console.log(result);
    if (result.success === false) {
        console.log("no success");
    } else {
        console.log("success");
    }
}, 'json')
```

This what `console.log(result)` outputs: `Object {success: true, errors: "", redirect_to: "/app_dev.php/login"}` but the conditional is not going through `no success` either `success`, why? Where I'm making the mistake?

Comment: try: `if (result.success) {
        console.log("success");
    } else {
        console.log("no success");
    }` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [jQuery.post() | jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/):

> **success**
>
> Type: Function( Object data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )
>
> A callback function that is executed if the request succeeds. Required
>   if dataType is provided, but can be null in that case.

Try adjusting your callback function definition from `function (result) {` to:

```
function( data, result ){
```

Then use the result string to run your conditional.

Without seeing more of what's going on behind the scenes with your $form object, I'd guess that something else there may be interrupting execution. Try NOT running the console.log() until after your conditional.